# Partition on hard drive after installing Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, resize

I installed Ubuntu by selecting the option 'Erase disk and Install Ubuntu'.

1. Now I want to make partition by resizing the 500 GB hard disk into another 2  partitions only for store random data (one NTFS and another ext4). For further clarification I want to mention that- 
   "I want 3 partitions in which first one will be for Ubuntu, second one is a NTFS partition and the third one is for ext4 partition."

   **I cannot do it with Gparted as it is showing some 'KEY' sign I guess. What should I do now?**
   [image: GParted]
2. I want to transfer data from a 1 TB external hard disk to my NTFS partition which is unmounted. what are the steps to follow?

Comment: log on with live session, open GParted and do the necessary partitions.. please note that backup is highly recommended. once you made NTFS partition in live session, exit from live session and then transfer the files from 1TB when you are logged on in your Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: As I am a new user, I cannot understand by the phrase, 'log on with live session'

Comment: live session means, "try Ubuntu" option when you installed Ubuntu 18.04, you have used either USB or DVD live installer.. with that you have to select "try Ubuntu" option. it will give access to all the partitions shown in the picture you attached. But be careful while partitioning.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did it without losing any data.